# Maven throws error UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, maven

I am seeing below error when trying to run maven. Java and javac is 1.7(versions are given below, and maven is 3.9.0. I am using mac os.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
mvn
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:425)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:140)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)

pwd
/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.9.1

java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

javac -version
javac 1.7.0_80
```

Comment: Maven 3.9 requires Java 8 (also known as 1.8) or later

Comment: It required Java 8 version try to build with 8 . https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html

Comment: First as already mentioned you have to have at minum JDK8 to run Maven 3.9.X Or you can use Maven 3.8.X (https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html)  and use JDK 7 ... other option would be to use a more recent JDK9+ and use the `release` option to produce JDK7 compatible compiled classes... apart from that JDK 7 is really out of date (current JDK version is JDK20 https://inside.java/2023/03/21/the-arrival-of-java-20/)... etc. or you can use toolchains (Details: https://youtu.be/-KbDcJcglPc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maven 3.9.x will require java 1.8. see [maven release history](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html)

You are getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

If you could see the error says that there is an unsupported version used and it gave you version 52.0.

This 52 version is associated with Java 1.8. check : [classFileStructure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-4.html)

In a nutshell, the error tells you that the maven implementation is compiled in Java 8, you are using the unsupported version. it is providing you the correct version.

Java 8 to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maven 3.9.1 requires at least Java 1.8. But you can still use Java 1.7 to build your application using the maven toolchain if your application requires Java 1.7.

In `${user.home}/.m2/toolchains.xml` configure the Jdk as follows.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toolchains>
  <!-- JDK toolchains -->
  <toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
      <version>1.7</version>
      <vendor>sun</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <jdkHome>/path/to/jdk/1.7</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
</toolchains>
```

And in your `pom.xml` configure the toolchain as follows.

```xml
<plugins>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>toolchain</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <toolchains>
        <jdk>
          <version>1.7</version>
          <vendor>sun</vendor>
        </jdk>
      </toolchains>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ...
</plugins>
```

> NOTE: Do not change the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable; it should point to Java 1.8 or a later version of java.

By using toolchains, Maven will use Java 1.8, and the project will be compiled using Java 1.7

REF: [Guide to Using Toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html)